# Accessing floats in a string list

Tags: python, string, list

To understand the different python data structures and their conversion, I came across a data frame which is displayed below:

[image]

The columns refer to ratings of the top 5 from each category i.e. Attraction , Hotel etc.

Here when I access the Attraction_Rating value for the first row in the dataframe, I get a string **'[4.5, 4.5,4.5,4.5,5.0]'**.

I wanted to understand how can we convert this string back to a list which contains these floats values without using regex. float(s) where s is a string, is clearly not applicable here and I couldn't think of any other simpler solution.

Can anyone please tell me how to do that or point me in the right direction here.

My output should be **[4.5, 4.5,4.5,4.5,5.0] i.e. list of floats.**

I'll really appreciate any help on this

Comment: You can use `eval`,  but you probably shouldn't. Why do you have a bunch of strings *representing python literals of lists of floats in the first place?*

Comment: Try this: df['Attraction_Rating'][0] Does it gives back the first value of the list, or the list itself?

Comment: The dataframe was like that. Any suggestion?

Comment: "the dataframe was like that" Um, dataframes don't just appear in your computer's main memory. *What made it like that*? Again, you can use `eval`, but the problem is that you have that string in the first place. You can also parse the string by splitting it, or various other ways (including regex, why *not* use regex?).

Comment: Yeah it doesn't. I've tried everything, plus I fear this will be closed by the moderators :D

Comment: Fundamentally, this means somewhere in this project someone has decided to dump a *string representation of a python list of floats* to a text file and call that serialization. That is the wrong way to do things.

Comment: Yes, it is. however I believe coming across such problems and finding a solution would be a good programming exercise. The below solution works very well.

Comment: @ShekharTanwar why didn't you want to use regex? That would also be a good solution.

Comment: I'm still in the beginning stages of Python, and regex was something I had planned to learn after I master the data structures part. Thanks everyone for the support.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, if you have read the question correct, how do you think it's a duplicate? I'm not sure why you had to mark it as duplicate when clearly this was a different problem statement.

Comment: You are asking how to turn a string representation of a list to that list. This is what that duplicate addresses.

Comment: I believe it's not. The link you shared , has the elements as strings <inside> the list, while here the quotes to denote a string value, are present outside the list itself. Also, I first referred the link you had shared, and couldn't find the answer. Anyway, I got the answer I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for a string like that.

```py
data_string = '[4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5]'

def convert(string):
  return list(map(lambda v: float(v), string[1:-1].split(',')))

print(convert(data_string))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works :)

Comment: You can just use `ast.literal_eval` here...

Comment: @JonClements is correct, my solution works without importing anything, but `ast.literal_eval` is simpler.

Comment: you can just use `eval` if you really don't want to import anything for some reason...

Comment: @ShekharTanwar just going to throw it out there... if you have an actual pandas dataframe of that format, then you can also do: `df.update(df.filter(regex='Rating$').applymap(ast.literal_eval))` to select the appropriate columns and update the dataframe in place with lists from the string representations.